# Passenger and i18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I´m using Rails 3.2.2 and when I tried to load my application on Passenger, I saw the error:

Could not find i18n-0.6.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

But I have installed this gem.

```
-bash-3.2$ bundle show i18n
/home/aeci/.gems/gems/i18n-0.6.0
```

This problem is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676890/passenger-says-bundlergemnotfound-error-while-the-bundle-install-says-its-ther), but someone have any idea what can I do? If the problem is Hosting service bug, what can I tell for my host company?

I've tried to delete gemfile.lock and create a new one, but doesn´t work.

Tks!

Answer (score 4):

The solution is:

```
cd application_name
$ bundle install --path vendor
$ bundle package
$ echo 'vendor/ruby' >> .gitignore
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case my project had a 'my_app' gemset configured, and passenger was trying to run the app with the 'default' gemset. This default gemset didn't had installed i18n so it was not possible to run it.

My solution was:

1. Use the default gemset wit rvm use 1.9.3 --default
2. bundle install
3. Done. Enjoy.

Hope this helps.