# Could not find i18n-0.6.4 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Opened up a Rails project I haven't coded in a while and I just tried starting up the Rails server with:

```
`rails s`
```

and I get this error message:

```
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize': Could not find i18n-0.6.4 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

Fwiw, I've done a `bundle install` and here's what I get when I check i18n:

```
$ gem list i18n

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

i18n (0.6.5)
```

Any idea what the problem is and how it should be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case your rails gem is in the Gemfile, you should run

```
bundle exec rails s
```

instead. HTH.

Comment: Yes, that does the job. Why does this work whereas `rails s` does not?

Answer (score 0):

There may be an issue with how you installed RVM.

Try calling gem list and see if it's mentioned anywhere there. 
There's a Rails guide to internationalization API. It may contain useful information if reintalling RVM doesn't fix anything

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

Comment: This link may prove useful as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676890/passenger-says-bundlergemnotfound-error-while-the-bundle-install-says-its-ther